# How to display data correctly from array using smarty?

Tags: php, html, css, smarty

When my consult return only one row, thats ok...
[image]

But when return more than one row my table crash
[image]

Output (second image and the error)

```
<table class="table-filtro">
                                    <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                                <th class="nome-quarto">TIpo</th>
                                                <th>N° Quarto</th>
                                                <th>Label</th>
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="14 th April 2011">14</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">14 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="15 th April 2011">15</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">15 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="16 th April 2011">16</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">16 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="17 th April 2011">17</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">17 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="18 th April 2011">18</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">18 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="19 th April 2011">19</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">19 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="20 th April 2011">20</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">20 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                                <th class="th-periodo" title="21 th April 2011">21</th>
                                                <!--<th class="th-periodo">21 de April de 2011</th>-->
                                                                                          </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                <td class="nome-quarto">Standard</td>
                                                <td>01</td>
                                                <td>Quarto padrão</td>

                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>

                                          </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                <td class="nome-quarto">Standard</td>
                                                <td>05</td>
                                                <td>Deluxe </td>

                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>

                                          </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                <td class="nome-quarto">Standard</td>
                                                <td>80</td>
                                                <td>Quarto novo </td>

                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 14 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 15 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 16 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 17 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 18 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 19 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 20 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="01 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="05 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/verde.jpg"></td>
                                                                                            <td><img title="80 -- 21 de April de 2011" src="http://casasbrancas.com.br/reservas/images/cubos/amarelo.jpg"></td>

                                          </tr>
                                                                              </tbody>
                              </table>
```

Template html code

```
                      <table class="table-filtro">
                            <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                        <th class="nome-quarto">TIpo</th>
                                        <th>N° Quarto</th>
                                        <th>Label</th>
                                            {foreach from=$numeros item="estoque"}
                                        <th class="th-periodo" title='{$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e th %B %Y"}'>{$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e"}</th>
                                            <!--<th class="th-periodo">{$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e de %B de %Y"}</th>-->
                                            {/foreach}
                                  </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    {foreach from=$listar item="estoque"}
                                  <tr>
                                        <td class="nome-quarto">{$estoque.tipo_nome}</td>
                                        <td>{if $estoque.quarto_numero|count_characters eq '1'}0{$estoque.quarto_numero}{else}{$estoque.quarto_numero}{/if}</td>
                                        <td>{$estoque.quarto_descricao}</td>

                                        {foreach from=$datas item="estoque"}
                                        <td><img title="{if $estoque.quarto_numero|count_characters eq '1'}0{$estoque.quarto_numero}{else}{$estoque.quarto_numero}{/if} -- {$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e de %B de %Y"}" src="http://{$smarty.server.SERVER_NAME}/reservas/images/cubos/{if $estoque.reserva_status eq '3'}vermelho{elseif $estoque.reserva_status eq '2'}amarelo{else}verde{/if}.jpg" /></td>
                                        {/foreach}

                                  </tr>
                                      {/foreach}
                            </tbody>
                      </table>
```

The PHP function

```
    function datas($data, $dias, $tipo) {
        $inicio = strtotime($data);
        $edia = date('d', $inicio); 
        $emes = date('m', $inicio);
        $eano = date('Y', $inicio);
        $db = new DBConfig();
        $db->config();
        $db->conn();

        $smarty_array = array();
        while($i <= $dias) {
            $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,date($emes),date($edia)+$i,date($eano))));
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quartos AS quartos 
                                  INNER JOIN tipos AS tipos 
                                  LEFT JOIN reservas AS reservas 
                                  ON quartos.quarto_tipo = tipos.tipo_id
                                  AND quartos.quarto_numero = reservas.reserva_quarto_id
                                  AND ".$today." BETWEEN reservas.reserva_checkin AND reservas.reserva_checkout
                                  WHERE quartos.quarto_tipo = '".$tipo."'
                                  GROUP BY quartos.quarto_id HAVING Count(*) >= 1") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                if (empty($row["reserva_status"])) {
                    $row["reserva_status"] = "0";
                }
                $row["reserva_checkin"] = $today; 
                $smarty_array[] = $row;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $db->close();
        return $smarty_array;
    }
```

Array

```
Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (24)
  0 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1302757200
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  1 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "15"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "5"
    quarto_descricao => "Deluxe "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => null
    reserva_quarto_id => null
    reserva_valor => null
    reserva_status => "0"
    reserva_cliente_id => null
    reserva_checkin => 1302757200
    reserva_checkout => null
    reserva_obs => null
  2 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "26"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "80"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto novo "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "3"
    reserva_quarto_id => "80"
    reserva_valor => "3000"
    reserva_status => "2"
    reserva_cliente_id => "58"
    reserva_checkin => 1302757200
    reserva_checkout => "1305090000"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  3 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1302843600
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  4 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "15"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "5"
    quarto_descricao => "Deluxe "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => null
    reserva_quarto_id => null
    reserva_valor => null
    reserva_status => "0"
    reserva_cliente_id => null
    reserva_checkin => 1302843600
    reserva_checkout => null
    reserva_obs => null
  5 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "26"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "80"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto novo "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "3"
    reserva_quarto_id => "80"
    reserva_valor => "3000"
    reserva_status => "2"
    reserva_cliente_id => "58"
    reserva_checkin => 1302843600
    reserva_checkout => "1305090000"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  6 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1302930000
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  7 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "15"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "5"
    quarto_descricao => "Deluxe "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => null
    reserva_quarto_id => null
    reserva_valor => null
    reserva_status => "0"
    reserva_cliente_id => null
    reserva_checkin => 1302930000
    reserva_checkout => null
    reserva_obs => null
  8 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "26"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "80"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto novo "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "3"
    reserva_quarto_id => "80"
    reserva_valor => "3000"
    reserva_status => "2"
    reserva_cliente_id => "58"
    reserva_checkin => 1302930000
    reserva_checkout => "1305090000"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  9 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1303016400
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  10 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "15"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "5"
    quarto_descricao => "Deluxe "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => null
    reserva_quarto_id => null
    reserva_valor => null
    reserva_status => "0"
    reserva_cliente_id => null
    reserva_checkin => 1303016400
    reserva_checkout => null
    reserva_obs => null
  11 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "26"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "80"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto novo "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "3"
    reserva_quarto_id => "80"
    reserva_valor => "3000"
    reserva_status => "2"
    reserva_cliente_id => "58"
    reserva_checkin => 1303016400
    reserva_checkout => "1305090000"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  12 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1303102800
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  13 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "15"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "5"
    quarto_descricao => "Deluxe "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => null
    reserva_quarto_id => null
    reserva_valor => null
    reserva_status => "0"
    reserva_cliente_id => null
    reserva_checkin => 1303102800
    reserva_checkout => null
    reserva_obs => null
  14 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "26"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "80"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto novo "
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "3"
    reserva_quarto_id => "80"
    reserva_valor => "3000"
    reserva_status => "2"
    reserva_cliente_id => "58"
    reserva_checkin => 1303102800
    reserva_checkout => "1305090000"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"
  15 => Array (15)
    quarto_id => "12"
    quarto_tipo => "1"
    quarto_numero => "1"
    quarto_descricao => "Quarto padrão"
    tipo_id => "1"
    tipo_nome => "Standard"
    tipo_foto => "03f9efa3b682512c74a9275656622b03.jpg"
    reserva_id => "4"
    reserva_quarto_id => "1"
    reserva_valor => "1600"
    reserva_status => "1"
    reserva_cliente_id => "62"
    reserva_checkin => 1303189200
    reserva_checkout => "1303534800"
    reserva_obs => "Aguardando pagamento"...
```

Comment: Can you post the output HTML for the table as well as the template HTML? Might make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In your nested `foreach` you're using `item="estoque"` twice.

For the line:

```
{foreach from=$datas item="estoque"}
```

you need to use a different name for `item` to avoid the loops overwriting each others' values.

Comment: Still breaking...the yellow square correspond to third line (and not third columm)...but i get the same result, (like the image)

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for your also are you getting smarty error or any other error for that matter ?

```
<table class="table-filtro">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th class="nome-quarto">TIpo</th>
                  <th>N° Quarto</th>
                  <th>Label</th>
                      {foreach from=$numeros item="estoque_1"}
                  <th class="th-periodo" title='{$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e th %B %Y"}'>{$estoque_1.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e"}</th>
                      <!--<th class="th-periodo">{$estoque.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e de %B de %Y"}</th>-->
                      {/foreach}
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
              {foreach from=$listar item="estoque_2"}
            <tr>
                  <td class="nome-quarto">{$estoque.tipo_nome}</td>
                  <td>{if $estoque_2.quarto_numero|count_characters eq '1'}0{$estoque_2.quarto_numero}{else}{$estoque_2.quarto_numero}{/if}</td>
                  <td>{$estoque.quarto_descricao}</td>

                  {foreach from=$datas item="estoque_3"}
                  <td><img title="{if $estoque_3.quarto_numero|count_characters eq '1'}0{$estoque_3.quarto_numero}{else}{$estoque_3.quarto_numero}{/if} -- {$estoque_3.reserva_checkin|date_format:"%e de %B de %Y"}" src="http://{$smarty.server.SERVER_NAME}/reservas/images/cubos/{if $estoque_3.reserva_status eq '3'}vermelho{elseif $estoque_3.reserva_status eq '2'}amarelo{else}verde{/if}.jpg" /></td>
                  {/foreach}

            </tr>
                {/foreach}
      </tbody>
</table>
```